# Turf.js - Type declarations not found when importing into Vue/Vite project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, turfjs

I use Turf.js's bbox functionality. No matter what I try, TS type definitions seem not to be found.

I tried the following:

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
    "@turf/turf": "6.5.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.11",
    ...
  },
```

Import in Vue file (using Composition API and TS):

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import * as turf from "@turf/turf";
...
</script>
```

TypeScript error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@turf/turf'. '/Users/.../node_modules/@turf/turf/dist/es/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  There are types at '/Users/.../node_modules/@turf/turf/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The '@turf/turf' library may need to update its package.json or typings.ts(7016)
```

Comment: When does the error occur? What is TS version? You may have different result

Comment: It occurs in the IDE (VSCode), and when running vue-tsc. I use the latest version of TypeScript - v.5.4.3 - in combination with Vite and vue-tsc.

I created a Replit here so that one can reproduce the error: https://replit.com/@amuedespache/Turfjs-Typescript